# Vue V-IF with a date comparison

Tags: javascript, vue.js

In my site I'm getting an object with a field called `available_at` which is a date in this format `2019-08-08`

I have a functioning html table using vue bindings but I don't know how to use a vue comparison for the timestamp above using Date.now()

```
<tr :class="[dateEvent.priority + '-priority', 'status-' + dateEvent.status]">
  <td v-if="dateEvent.task_typet_id === '2' && dateEvent.name === 'Task Title' && dateEvent.available_at === Date.now()">{{ dateEvent.task_identifier }}</td>
</tr>
```

How can I successfully have it check that field against the current date?

Answer (score 0):

A few points:

- JavaScript `Date` objects include a time value, so using the equality comparison `===` will require that they match to the millisecond. You probably don't want that.
- You can convert a string to a `Date` object using the constructor, e.g.:

```
     new Date("2019-08-08")
```

will create a date corresponding to midnight on August 8.

- Be careful how you handle time zones. Is the date provided in a local time zone or in UTC?

I'd suggest using a computed property to simplify the template, and then check out the various methods available for [`Date`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date) objects to see how to construct a comparison that matches your application's requirements.

Comment: it's all local time zone driven, but this would be loading every day so I only want to show the records available on the current day. So are you saying i would put available_at through date like ``` new Date(dateEvent.available_at)``` ?

Comment: Yes, that will create a `Date` object that can be used for comparison.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to check if both dates are on the same day you could try:

```
function isSameDay(date1, date2){
  return date1.getFullYear() === date2.getFullYear() &&
    date1.getMonth() === date2.getMonth() &&
    date1.getDay() === date2.getDay()
}

console.log(isSameDay(new Date(), new Date(dateEvent.available_at))
```

You can also try libraries like [`moment`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/moment) to deal with different date locales.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [moment](https://momentjs.com/docs/#/parsing/) for this :

```
moment().isSame(dateEvent.available_at, 'day');
```

This compares the current date with the one in `dateEvent.available_at` by `'day'` only.